# Firebase Database not Uploading

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I have my upload code here

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

    let chatRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("chat")
    let userUid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    var userName = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var topBar: UINavigationItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var inputTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    topBar.title = "Chat Log Controller"
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/\(userUid!)/name").observe(.value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        self.userName = (snap.value! as! String).description
    }
}

@IBAction func handleSend(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let childChatRef = chatRef.childByAutoId()
    let message = inputTextField.text!
    childChatRef.child("text").setValue(message)
    print(inputTextField.text)
}

@IBAction func handleSendByEnter(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let childChatRef = chatRef.childByAutoId()
    let message = inputTextField.text!
    print(userName)
    childChatRef.child("name").setValue(userName)
    childChatRef.child("text").setValue(message)
    print(inputTextField.text)
}
```

}

text is successfully uploaded But
It doesn't print userName and doesn't upload it to Firebase Database
But username is nut nil!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use your observer code as,

```
ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
```

}

Comment: when I print snapshot.value, It print's well but later when I print my userName variable, It doesn't prints anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just take `self.username = snap.value! as! String`
It will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you post the photo of print (snap)